# Strange situation with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello I am trying to connect to a database using C# but keeps giving me this the code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FAVAI_LAB_01\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DBServicios;Integrated Security=True");

try
{
   connection.Open();

   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select ID_USUARIO from TUSUARIO" +
                                         "WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO=@Param1 AND PASS=@Param2", connection);
   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", username);
   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", password);

   string CurrentName = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

   if (CurrentName != null)
   {
      connection.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("true");
   }
   else
   {
      connection.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("falsfgdge");
   }
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

This is the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
 The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
 (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.
 Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, 
 Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, 
 Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword,
 Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, 
 SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, 
 Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, 
 DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, 
 DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) 
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) 
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, 
 DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() 
 at Webserver.Login.getAccess(String username, String password) in path\Login.cs:line 18
```

Comment: Where is raised the exception? At the Open ot at the ExecuteScalar?

Comment: And perhaps, to better understand the exact error message try to print just `e.Message` for debugging

Comment: How i can make an sql exception on my code like Java that is try{}catch(SQLException e){}?

Comment: Also note that you should not just be catching `SqlException`, as the SqlClient calls can throw other types of exceptions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting ID_USUARIO but then you cast it to string. Most probably, if a column is called ID_something the type of it is NOT a string type.

Comment: Thanks that was part of the mistake.

Comment: +1 that is probably the source of the unknown error message that I have asked to show.

Answer (score 2):

A space is missing between TUSUARIO and WHERE, add one

```
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select ID_USUARIO from TUSUARIO " +
                            "WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO=@Param1 AND PASS=@Param2", connection);
```

Comment: Yes, but without the exact error message it is difficult to say if this is the raising error. Also the name of the server is suspect. This is the reason to know the exact error message

Comment: I fix it and still give me the same mistake.

Comment: Another try: Remove the SQLSERVER from the connection string. Leave only FAVAI_LAB_01. But really the message of the exception is fundamental to understand

Comment: If i remove the SQLSERVER is not going to find the server.